# Compare multimodal distributions for different groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, kernel-smoothing, kruskal-wallis-test, multimodality

I am analyzing data from 3 different gait speeds. For each group/speed, I am determining specific value called "angle". Each group has different sample size. So, I need to compare multimodal distributions and I would like to statistically test following:

1. There is significant difference between 3 modes (peaks) within each group
2. There is no significant difference between same modes for all three groups (comparing to other 2 modes).
   Distributions are shown below, and it is noticable that the 3 modes for each group appear around same value, relative to each other.
   [image: Multimodal distributions]

I am stucked with this. I have tried KDE, and I got 3 expected clusters. I am not sure how to prove the difference. I have also tried Kruskal-Wallis nonparametric test (for different sample sizes), but the results show significant difference between groups, and I think the distributions are not statistically different (2. point from above).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the first point, I have also tried to separate the clusters with simple thresholds, and then use the Kruskal-Wallis test to check if there is significant difference between three groupes (modes), and I didi this for all 3 groupes (gait speeds). KW showed that there is significant difference -which is OK.

Comment: I am stucked with the 2nd point. When I separate 3 peakes/modes/groupes with heuristic thresholds (not KDE, since then I cannot use KW test), and check difference between different speeds - I get significant difference. But what I want, is to compare the difference RELATIVE to other 2 modes/peaks. Then, the result I would like is "no significant difference between first modes for all 3 speeds, comparing to other modes". I do not know how to check this. Any help would be VERY appriciated. Thanks.